# RTK Query slice endpoint - useGetProductsQuery is not a function

Tags: rtk-query

My `useGetProductsQuery` is not being recognized  for some reason.

productsApiSlice.js

```
import { PRODUCTS_URL } from "../constants";
import { apiSlice } from "./apiSlice";

export const productsApiSlice = apiSlice.injectEndpoints({
    endpoints: (builder) => ({
        getProducts: builder.query({
            query: () => ({
                url: PRODUCTS_URL,
            }),
            keepUnusedDataFor: 5,
        }),
    }),
});

export const { useGetProductsQuery } = productsApiSlice;
```

component:

```
import { useGetProductsQuery } from "../slices/productsApiSlice";

function HomeScreen() {
    const { data: products, isLoading, error } = useGetProductsQuery();

    return (
        <div className="row">
            {isLoading ? (
                <h2>Loading...</h2>
            ) : error ? (
                <div>{error?.data?.message || error.error}</div>
            ) : (
                <p>test</p>
            )}
        </div>
    );
}
```

I get the following error:

```
    (0 , _slices_productsApiSlice__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.useGetProductsQuery) is not a function
TypeError: (0 , _slices_productsApiSlice__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.useGetProductsQuery) is not a function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This usually happens if `createApi` is not imported from the React-specific entry point `@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react`, but from the framework-agnostic `@reduxjs/toolkit/query`.

Can you please check your imports?

Comment: Not sure why it works in the tutorial I watched, he explicitly uses `@reduxjs/toolkit/query` and it works.

Comment: That has never worked and never will. Probably editing magic.